# Is There A Way to make complex Markdown Table?

Tags: markdown

I Wanted to create a markdown table
[image: Complex table]

but can't get it right:

```
| Available     | Process   | Allocation       |     Max         |
|---------------|-----------|:----------------:|----------------:|
| A | B | C | D |           |   A | B | C | D  | A | B | C | D   |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | 0 | P0        |   0 | 0 | 1 | 2  | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2   |
|               | P1        |   1 | 0 | 0 | 0  | 1 | 7 | 5 | 0   |
|               | P2        |   1 | 3 | 5 | 4  | 2 | 3 | 5 | 6   |
|               | P3        |   0 | 6 | 3 | 2  | 0 | 6 | 5 | 2   |
|               | P4        |   0 | 0 | 1 | 4  | 0 | 6 | 5 | 6   |
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Markdown supports some HTML syntax, such as `<table>` elements.
To make a column like the headers on the image, the magic attribute is

```
colspan="X"
```

Where X is the number of columns you want it to extend to, as well as

```
rowspan="Y"
```

Where Y is the number of rows you want it to extend to

For example:

```css
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      Available
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2">
      Processes
    </td>
    <td colspan="4">
      Allocation
    </td>
    <td colspan="4">
      Max
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      A
    </td>
    <td>
      B
    </td>
    <td>
      C
    </td>
    <td>
      D
    </td>
    <td>
      A
    </td>
    <td>
      B
    </td>
    <td>
      C
    </td>
    <td>
      D
    </td>
    <td>
      A
    </td>
    <td>
      B
    </td>
    <td>
      C
    </td>
    <td>
      D
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      1
    </td>
    <td>
      5
    </td>
    <td>
      2
    </td>
    <td>
      0
    </td>
    <td>
      P0
    </td>
    <td>
      0
    </td>
    <td>
      0
    </td>
    <td>
      1
    </td>
    <td>
      2
    </td>
    <td>
      0
    </td>
    <td>
      0
    </td>
    <td>
      1
    </td>
    <td>
      2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
    </td>
    <td>
      P1
    </td>
    <td>
      1
    </td>
    <td>
      0
    </td>
    <td>
      0
    </td>
    <td>
      0
    </td>
    <td>
      1
    </td>
    <td>
      7
    </td>
    <td>
      5
    </td>
    <td>
      0
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that CSS is only necessary here because the Markdown interpreter will be rendering the table with the default styling.

Answer (score 4):

> **Pro Markdowning tip:** Always start by checking results at [BabelMark](https://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=%7C+Available+++++%7C+Process+++%7C+Allocation+++++++%7C+++++Max+++++++++%7C%0A%7C---------------%7C-----------%7C%3A----------------%3A%7C----------------%3A%7C%0A%7C+A+%7C+B+%7C+C+%7C+D+%7C+++++++++++%7C+++A+%7C+B+%7C+C+%7C+D++%7C+A+%7C+B+%7C+C+%7C+D+++%7C%0A%7C+1+%7C+5+%7C+2+%7C+0+%7C+P0++++++++%7C+++0+%7C+0+%7C+1+%7C+2++%7C+0+%7C+0+%7C+1+%7C+2+++%7C%0A%7C+++++++++++++++%7C+P1++++++++%7C+++1+%7C+0+%7C+0+%7C+0++%7C+1+%7C+7+%7C+5+%7C+0+++%7C%0A%7C+++++++++++++++%7C+P2++++++++%7C+++1+%7C+3+%7C+5+%7C+4++%7C+2+%7C+3+%7C+5+%7C+6+++%7C%0A%7C+++++++++++++++%7C+P3++++++++%7C+++0+%7C+6+%7C+3+%7C+2++%7C+0+%7C+6+%7C+5+%7C+2+++%7C%0A%7C+++++++++++++++%7C+P4++++++++%7C+++0+%7C+0+%7C+1+%7C+4++%7C+0+%7C+6+%7C+5+%7C+6+++%7C) to see which renderer gets closest and edit from there!

Your original code gets close in MultiMarkdown, which [you can preview at BabelMark](https://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=%7C+Available+++++%7C+Process+++%7C+Allocation+++++++%7C+++++Max+++++++++%7C%0A%7C---------------%7C-----------%7C%3A----------------%3A%7C----------------%3A%7C%0A%7C+A+%7C+B+%7C+C+%7C+D+%7C+++++++++++%7C+++A+%7C+B+%7C+C+%7C+D++%7C+A+%7C+B+%7C+C+%7C+D+++%7C%0A%7C+1+%7C+5+%7C+2+%7C+0+%7C+P0++++++++%7C+++0+%7C+0+%7C+1+%7C+2++%7C+0+%7C+0+%7C+1+%7C+2+++%7C%0A%7C+++++++++++++++%7C+P1++++++++%7C+++1+%7C+0+%7C+0+%7C+0++%7C+1+%7C+7+%7C+5+%7C+0+++%7C%0A%7C+++++++++++++++%7C+P2++++++++%7C+++1+%7C+3+%7C+5+%7C+4++%7C+2+%7C+3+%7C+5+%7C+6+++%7C%0A%7C+++++++++++++++%7C+P3++++++++%7C+++0+%7C+6+%7C+3+%7C+2++%7C+0+%7C+6+%7C+5+%7C+2+++%7C%0A%7C+++++++++++++++%7C+P4++++++++%7C+++0+%7C+0+%7C+1+%7C+4++%7C+0+%7C+6+%7C+5+%7C+6+++%7C).

It's a few tweaks away from what you want.

---

#### With tweaks

MultiMarkdown (MMD) does support colspans, and seems to do what you want with this MultiMarkdown code:

```
| Available  |||| Process   | Allocation    ||||     Max      ||||
|---|---|---|---|-----------|-----|---|---|----|---|---|---|-----|
| A | B | C | D |           |   A | B | C | D  | A | B | C | D   |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | 0 | P0        |   0 | 0 | 1 | 2  | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2   |
|            |||| P1        |   1 | 0 | 0 | 0  | 1 | 7 | 5 | 0   |
|            |||| P2        |   1 | 3 | 5 | 4  | 2 | 3 | 5 | 6   |
|            |||| P3        |   0 | 6 | 3 | 2  | 0 | 6 | 5 | 2   |
|            |||| P4        |   0 | 0 | 1 | 4  | 0 | 6 | 5 | 6   |
```

You can double-check on [BabelMark](https://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=%7C+Available++%7C%7C%7C%7C+Process+++%7C+Allocation++++%7C%7C%7C%7C+++++Max++++++%7C%7C%7C%7C%0A%7C---%7C---%7C---%7C---%7C-----------%7C-----%7C---%7C---%7C----%7C---%7C---%7C---%7C-----%7C%0A%7C+A+%7C+B+%7C+C+%7C+D+%7C+++++++++++%7C+++A+%7C+B+%7C+C+%7C+D++%7C+A+%7C+B+%7C+C+%7C+D+++%7C%0A%7C+1+%7C+5+%7C+2+%7C+0+%7C+P0++++++++%7C+++0+%7C+0+%7C+1+%7C+2++%7C+0+%7C+0+%7C+1+%7C+2+++%7C%0A%7C++++++++++++%7C%7C%7C%7C+P1++++++++%7C+++1+%7C+0+%7C+0+%7C+0++%7C+1+%7C+7+%7C+5+%7C+0+++%7C%0A%7C++++++++++++%7C%7C%7C%7C+P2++++++++%7C+++1+%7C+3+%7C+5+%7C+4++%7C+2+%7C+3+%7C+5+%7C+6+++%7C%0A%7C++++++++++++%7C%7C%7C%7C+P3++++++++%7C+++0+%7C+6+%7C+3+%7C+2++%7C+0+%7C+6+%7C+5+%7C+2+++%7C%0A%7C++++++++++++%7C%7C%7C%7C+P4++++++++%7C+++0+%7C+0+%7C+1+%7C+4++%7C+0+%7C+6+%7C+5+%7C+6+++%7C%0A)

[image: multimarkdown rendering]

[More on MultiMarkdown here](https://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/).

---

#### Rendering in MultiMarkdown

If you're not familiar with running Perl or want live preview of edits, [there is a Multimarkdown texteditor **for macOS**](https://multimarkdown.com/composer4/) for sale by MMD's creator.

If you're on Windows, I don't think there's an editor with full MMD support out of the box. You can learn Perl or you can get practically identical results with an app I've written* for Windows, [MarkUpDown](http://markupdown.com/), which [supports MMD tables](http://markupdown.com/faq.html#answer3).

If you're on Linux, I'll assume you can spell Perl. ;^D

---

<sub>*I'm offering this b/c I don't know of another app on Windows that supports MMD tables out of the box, and I know (intimately) that this one does. As [the FAQ at one time said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/184684), *Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product, so be it*. But honestly, MMD is Perl. If you want to do it for free, you can!</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create this complex table in markdown. you need to write HTML tables as given by Jacob in his answer. What you have to do is, as `<table>` is a block element, create new line before and after it.

```
Your markdown content before

<table>... </table>

Your markdown content after
```

Markdown is not a replacement for HTML. As creator of Markdown, John Gruber puts it:

> INLINE HTML Markdown’s syntax is intended for one purpose: to be used
>   as a format for writing for the web.
>
> Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it. Its
>   syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of
>   HTML tags. The idea is not to create a syntax that makes it easier to
>   insert HTML tags. In my opinion, HTML tags are already easy to insert.
>   The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and edit
>   prose. HTML is a publishing format; Markdown is a writing format.
>   Thus, Markdown’s formatting syntax only addresses issues that can be
>   conveyed in plain text.
>
> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply
>   use HTML itself. There’s no need to preface it or delimit it to
>   indicate that you’re switching from Markdown to HTML; you just use the
>   tags.
>
> The only restrictions are that block-level HTML elements — e.g. `<div>,
>   <table>, <pre>, <p>, etc.` — must be separated from surrounding content
>   by blank lines, and the start and end tags of the block should not be
>   indented with tabs or spaces. Markdown is smart enough not to add
>   extra (unwanted) `<p>` tags around HTML block-level tags.

[Reference Markdown HTML Documentation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html)